# postMessage from one iframe to another

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, dynamic, postmessage

**How to send the height of the inner iframe to its parent iframe?**

I am building a web widget. For configuration of the web widget, I built a generator to generate the widget code. It also previews the current selections and changes made to the widget using an iframe. Both iframes live inside of the same server (cdn.domain.com). The intranet lives somewhere else (intranet.domain.com).

The generator is embeded inside of an intranet. Therefore it is inside of an iframe, whichs leaves me with a parent (intranet), an iframe (generator) and another iframe (web widget) nested inside of each other. To set the web widget's height dynamically it posts its height to the top window. When using it inside of the intranet the top window is the intranet and not the generator itself.

Inner iframe:

```
function iframeHeightHandler() {

    let height = document.body.scrollHeight;

    //window.top refers to parent window
    window.top.postMessage(["setHeight", height], "*");
    window.top.frames[1].postMessage(["setHeight", height], "*"); // this line results in a CORS block error
    console.log('msg sent: '+ height + 'px' +' (iframe.js)');
}
// pass iframe height to parent
window.addEventListener('load', iframeHeightHandler);
window.addEventListener('resize', iframeHeightHandler);
```

Outer iframe:

```
// reset height to actual height
let msgNumber = 0;
window.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
    let eventName = e.data[0];
    let data = e.data[1];
    let origin = e.origin;
    if (origin == 'https://cdn.domain.com/') {
        switch(eventName) {
            case 'setHeight':
            for (let i=0; i<iframes.length; i++) {
                if (i == msgNumber) {
                    iframes[i].querySelector('.iframe-'+i).style.height = data + 'px';
                }
            }
            if (msgNumber+1 == iframes.length) {
                msgNumber = 0;
            } else {
                msgNumber++;
            }
            break;
        }
        console.log('message received: '+ data + 'px' +' (embed.js)');
    } else {
        console.log('origin not allowed');
    }
    console.log(origin);
} , false);
```

I hope someone can help...

Comment: You've provided a bunch of code which a cursory glance suggests should do what you want. What problem do you have with it?

Comment: window.top.frames[1].postMessage(["setHeight", height], "*"); // this line results in a CORS block error

This is basically the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> window.top.frames[1].postMessage(["setHeight", height], "*");
> ```
>
> this line results in a CORS block error

You cannot access the contents of frames across origins.

You can use `postMessage` to send a message to a frame, even across origins.

The problem with that code is that the first half (`window.top.frames[1]`) is trying to access the contents of a frame before the second half tries to post a message to a frame inside it.

There's no direct connection between the document your JS is running in and the document you want to send the message to. This means you can't *directly* post messages between them.

You can (probably, I've not tried this, I haven't used nested frames this century) use an intermediary.

- Send a message to the top level document: `window.top.postMessage`
- Have an `message` event listener in the top level document that listens for that message and relays it to the target frame (`window.frames[1].postMessage`)

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I tried it but it seems that from the top level, you can't access the inner iframe. How would you approach this scenario? Is there a better way than a nested iframe?